# How to get linked workitem by the build for stakeholders

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are developing internal tool using .NET Azure DevOps API that need to fetch list of last build from Azure DevOps, and for each build find related work item(s). This tool should work with stakeholder access level.

We've already implemented getting the list of builds and it works fine.
Is it possible to find related work item(s) without access to a branch - which is not accessible for stakeholders?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the work items that are referenced by the build using the REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Needless to say, you do need to have the work items associated to the commits that form part of the build.